# Implicit bool evaluation with if conditions

Tags: c++, c

I have an integer called "count" which increments when a certain condition is met. So I wanted to ask what happens if you write this condition:

```
if(count % 2)
{
    return even_bit; 
}
else
{
    return odd_bit;
}
```

The question is basically asking if the if condition above is checking for the condition count%2 = 0 or count%2 !=0 when you don't explicitly define it in the expression for integer data type variables.

Comment: Why can't you just compile and run the code?

Comment: `0` is `false`, any other integer value is `true`.

Comment: What do you mean by "which of these conditions get evaluated"? I only see one condition.

Comment: In C language programming, programmers were using 0 and 1 instead of false and true, C++ has datatype bool and you can define `bool myvar;` However , such as last , you can use 0 and 1.

Comment: This question, I'm afraid, is as clear as mud. Are you asking what `%` does?

Comment: Basically asking if(count % 2) : if the condition here is equivalent to saying if(count % 2 !=0). Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: There are lot of answers and explanations in [Using boolean values in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921539/using-boolean-values-in-c). Please search the site before asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If an expression evaluates to `0`, it will be interpreted as `FALSE` - for any non-zero value, it will be interpreted as `TRUE`. In other words,

```
if(count % 2)
```

is equivalent to

```
if(count % 2 != 0)
```

So your code is "backwards". If the statement is true, `count` is odd and you most likely would want to return the `odd_bit` (just guessing here.).

Comment: Which is, of course, why you would never actually want to write it the way he did.  If the expression has type `bool`, then it's fine (and in fact any further comparisons, e.g. to `true` or to `false` would be confusing).  If it's not `bool`, you don't count on a somewhat obscure and confusing implicit conversion, you write the conversion you want.

Comment: @JamesKanze It's a matter of opinion. I usually prefer to avoid unnecessary comparison and *especially* when it comes to the % operator. The result of % operator is the remainder. The boolean evaluation of that result answers a question *whether* there is some remainder.

Comment: @JamesKanze Many C programmers are used to common idioms for other operators as well, e.g. `if (flag & MY_FLAG_NAME)` is also usually preferable in comparison with `if (flag & MY_FLAG_NAME == MY_FLAG_NAME)`, etc.

Comment: Thanks very much. That answered my question. it is the even parity bit i am setting, which is one when there are odd number of ones.

Comment: Glad it helped. I hope you do realize that this function does **not** return the parity bit of `count`. You would have to do something a bit more advanced for that. See for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19373034/how-to-judge-if-there-is-even-1s-in-a-numbers-binary-representation-using-c/19373277#19373277 for a method (and several explanations, including my own brilliant one... :-) )

Comment: @PavelŠimerda I don't think its so much a matter of opinion, but rather hiding important information (in other words, obfuscation).  There's an implicit conversion to `bool`, and implicit conversions generally make the code less readable.  `if` selects not on whether there is a remainder or not, but on whether the expression evaluates true or not.  Using some self invented other definition, like "there is a remainer" is obfuscation, whether it works or not.

Comment: @PavelŠimerda Many C programmers have bad habits.  Even back when I was learning C (in the 1980's), we knew enough to write `if ( (flag & MY_FLAG_NAME) != 0 )`.  (Although I know a few exceptions, I suspect that most people who wrote good C have moved on to C++.  There's really no reason to use C today.)

Comment: @JamesKanze Yes and there have always been programmers who thought their habits are the good ones and everyone else is wrong. Religion and technology don't fit well together.

Comment: @PavelŠimerda It's not a question of religion or habits.  It's a question of expressing oneself clearly or not.

Comment: I am with James on this one. Clarity trumps compactness in code every time - a few more characters typed today saves a ton of pain tomorrow. Yay for `-Wall -pedantic` flags.

Comment: @Floris I respect other people's feelings and opinions even when they aren't the same as mine. I personally consider `if (flag & MY_FLAG_NAME)` much more readable than `if ( (flag & MY_FLAG_NAME) != 0)` and that's a very basic one. Once the lines get longer and more complicated, e.g. a `== 0` at the and looks like a `no` at the and of a sentence reversing the whole meaning. But that doesn't mean I want to turn it into religion.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(count % 2)
```

is equivalent to

```
if(count % 2 != 0)
```

Now it will all depend on `count` whether it is even or odd. In case of even, `count%2` is `FALSE` (return `odd_bit`) and if `count` is odd then `count%2` is `TRUE` (return `even_bit`).

Comment: Actually, it's the equivalent of `if ( static_cast<bool>( count % 2 ) )`.  Which is, effectively the same as `if ( count % 2 != 0 )`.  I don't know where you got the third variant from.

Comment: The third variant is incorrect, because _any_ non-zero expression will evaluate to true.

Comment: @JamesKanze; Yes you are right.